# Problem with import component in react-native - typeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, import, tsconfig, native-base

I have a problem with import my component when it's in `./src/components/CustomButton/index.tsx` and when im using defined paths in tsconfig. Then my import looks like
`import CustomButton from '@components/CustomButton'`

But when i save it not in index.tsx and without using directory but just in /components/CustomButton.tsx and then
`import CutomButton from '../components/CustomButton.tsx'`
everything works fine.

How to make first version work properly?

Import error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmSRu.png)

CustomButton index.tsx

```
import {Button} from 'native-base';


const CustomButton = ({
  children,
  dark,
  onPress,
  isDisabled,
  bold,
  isLoading,
  mt,
}: any) => (
  <Button
    _text={{
      color: `${dark ? 'white' : 'black'}`,
      fontWeight: `${bold ? 'bold' : 'normal'}`,
      fontSize: 16,
    }}
    bg={dark ? 'muted.20' : 'muted.10'}
    colorScheme="muted"
    onPress={onPress}
    isDisabled={isDisabled}
    isLoading={isLoading}
    style={{borderRadius: 10}}
    p="4"
    mt={mt}>
    {children}
  </Button>
);

export default CustomButton;
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["/*"],
      "@api/*": ["/apiActions/*"],
      "@components/*": [
        "/components/*"
      ],
      "@context/*": [
        "/Context/*"
      ],
      "@interfaces/*": [
        "/Interfaces/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "/utils/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
  ]
}
```

How to make first version work properly? I've search a lot here and in other pages but i didn't find the answer

Comment: Consider adding it to your `babel.config.js` as well

Answer (score 0):

it has been a while since I set up my react-native project.

I can't remember for sure, but I believe this was my solution:

1. add `babel-plugin-root-import` to devDependencies

   `yarn add -D babel-plugin-root-import`
2. open `babel.config.js` and add `babel-plugin-root-import` in plugins

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
   return {
      ...
      plugins: [
　　      // Add this line
         [
　　　　　　   'babel-plugin-root-import',
             {
                root: __dirname,
                rootPathPrefix: '@',
                rootPathSuffix: 'src',
             },
　　　　　 ]
      ]
   }
}
```

If it doesn't work, please let me know and I'll try to remember it again.

Another solution is to add `package.json` in your folder. For example on components folder add package.json and write this:

```json
{
   "name": "@components"
}
```

Additionally, I believe you can write your tsconfig.json file more succinctly by removing

```json
      "@api/*": ["/apiActions/*"],
      "@components/*": [
        "/components/*"
      ],
      "@context/*": [
        "/Context/*"
      ],
      "@interfaces/*": [
        "/Interfaces/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "/utils/*"
      ]
    }
```

in your paths and change to this

```json
"paths": {
   "@*": ["src/*"]
},
```